# Converting functions from type T to type U>:T

Tags: scala, set, contravariance

I have a question about creating a contravariant set represented by a function T=>Boolean that returns true if something is in the set, false otherwise. It looks like this:

```
class BoolSet[-T](f: T=>Boolean) {

  def contains(x:T): Boolean = f(x)

  def add(x:T): BoolSet[T] = return new BoolSet[T](((y: T)=> f(y) || y==x))

  def remove(x:T): BoolSet[T] = if(f(x)) return new BoolSet[T](((y: T)=> f(y) && y!=x)) else return this

  def union[U>:T](s : BoolSet[U]) : BoolSet[U] = return new BoolSet[U](((y: U) => this.contains(y) || s.contains(y)))

}
```

I'm having problems with the union function, because `this.contains` is a function `T=>Boolean` rather than `U=>Boolean`. How can I convert this function from taking type T to type U?

I don't understand why this doesn't work as T is a Subtype of U, so surely everything U can do T can also do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the signature of method `union` to

```
def union[U<:T](s : BoolSet[U]) : BoolSet[U]
```

or

```
def union[U>:T](s : BoolSet[U]) : BoolSet[T]
```

The reason is that type `T` is **contravariant** in class `BoolSet`, which mean `BoolSet[A]` is a subtype of `BoolSet[B]` if `B <: A`.

Comment: Yes, I actually just saw this myself the moment before I saw your post. Silly me. Thanks anyway.